# Convert SQL date to hebrew

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to convert a english date stored in a sql table to hebrew, there are probably some ways to doing this but i don't know any of them.
the website I'm working on runs on html, css, javascript/jquery and php as well as sql for the data.
maybe there's a sql function that converts dates or maybe in php?

Comment: Look [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-convert-a-posts-dateyear-from-gregorian-calendar-to-hebrew-calendar).

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Just make sure you are changing this in the display layer only. **DO NOT CHANGE THE FORMAT IN THE DATABASE!**

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Comment: this one works fine https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jdtojewish.php#35453 just replace `split` for `explode`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it on Hebrew, but if you convert your English date to a timestamp, you can use [`strftime()`](https://php.net/strftime) (in php...) to format it.

Obviously the correct locale needs to be installed on the server and you need to set it in your php script using `setlocale()` as well.

An example:

```
// First convert your date to a timestamp if it is not already
// $timestamp contains the timestamp

// set the locale
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he');
// possibly setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL'); or setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he_IL', 'hebrew');

// echo the date:
echo strftime('%A %e %B', $timestamp);

// or just show the current date:
echo strftime('%A %e %B');
```

If you need to see what locales are installed on your system, you can do that from the command line (linux....):

```
$ locale -a
```

or in php:

```
system('locale -a');
```

check the manual on [`setlocale()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) for more information.

Comment: i haven't really heard of 'locales' could you please provide me with some info or links on what it is and what they do, I'd very much appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @effy I have added an example.